# How do you calculate spell ability and spell save dc?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

So I read this:

> Spell save DC = **8** + your proficiency bonus + your Intelligence modifier
>    Spell attack modifier = your proficiency bonus + your Intelligence modifier

Now, in this case is **8** just a base number or is that supposed to be the intelligence score? I am mainly confused because if it is the score and that is for a wizard that it very low. I'm trying to determine the numbers I would then require to place for spellcasting ability, spell save dc and spell attack bonus.

Comment: Is English not your first language? For our downvoters, sometimes if English is not one's first language the rules text can be a bit perplexing.  Heck, English is my first language and I now and again find the text as written perplexing. And I'm reasonably good at figuring things out.

Answer (score 11):

It's just the base number, not your intelligence score or any other stat. Note that the proficiency bonus is 2 at first level, so it adds up to 10 + modifier at first level, 11 + modifier at fifth level, 12 + modifier at ninth level and so on.

Answer (score 5):

### Base number for Save DC

The spell save DC is 8 + proficiency bonus + intelligence modifier. At level 1 with a Int of say 15 (which mod is +2), you'd have 8 + 2 + 2 = 12.

For attack there isn't a base.  Your spell Attack is your intelligence modifier + proficiency bonus. Using the the example of a level 1 with 15 Int, you get 2 + 2 = 4.